# Reading piped input with C++

Tags: c++, pipe, stdin, cin

I am using the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    string lineInput = " ";
    while(lineInput.length()>0) {
        cin >> lineInput;
        cout << lineInput;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

With the following command:
`echo "Hello" | test.exe`

This result is an infinite loop printing "Hello". How can I make it read and print a single "Hello"?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
string lineInput;
while (cin >> lineInput) {
  cout << lineInput;
}
```

If you really want full lines, use:

```
string lineInput;
while (getline(cin,lineInput)) {
  cout << lineInput;
}
```

Comment: this does not allow you to make user input after.

Answer (score 12):

When `cin` fails to extract, it doesn't change the target variable.  So whatever string your program last read successfully is stuck in `lineInput`.

You need to check `cin.fail()`, and [Erik has shown the preferred way to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446161/reading-piped-input-with-c/5446172#5446172).