# Difficulty in passing command line arguments

Tags: linux

I want to pass command line to my c program by reading another file using cat command as follows:

```
cat data | ./file
```

contents of the file data are

```
abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yz
```

and code of the file.c is

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int args, char * argv[] )
{
     int i = 0;
     for( i; i < args; i++ )
     {
         printf(argv[i]);
         printf("\n");
     }
}
```

when the code is run as follows

```
cat a | ./file
```

it just display the file name and don't display the a contents. Am I doing it right?

Answer (score 2):

You should try something like:

```
./file $(cat a)
```

Comment: In this way, it works fine. but I want to do in the above-mentioned way.

Answer (score 2):

The pipe is treated as `STDIN` fd instead of command line arguments.

You may need `cat a | xargs ./file`.

```
leetom@leetoms-MBP:~$ cat aa.txt
aaa bbb cc
leetom@leetoms-MBP:~$ cat aa.txt | xargs ./a.out
./a.out
aaa
bbb
cc
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read piped input from the standard input stream with `cin` as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446161/reading-piped-input-with-c). Your file would become:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main( int args, char ** argv )
{

    std::string lineInput;
    while (std::cin >> lineInput) {
        std::cout << lineInput << std::endl;
    }

}
```

Then your approach will work directly:

```
$ cat data | ./file
abc
def
ghi
jkl
mno
pqr
stu
vwx
yz
```