# How do I read the whole command line?

Tags: c++, linux, bash, command

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for( count = 0; count < argc; count++ )
    {

         cout << "  argv[" << count << "]" << argv[count] << "\n" <<      endl;           
     }
}
```

Command `$ ls -l | ./main.out`

The output will show

```
Command-line arguments :
argv[0]    ./main.out
```

My question is, how do I make my program to read the command before that, `ls -l`

Comment: AFAIK you can't.  Those parameters are not passed to the program.

Comment: Aside: If you're trying to do so: [Don't parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Command line parameters are passed as arguments when calling the program. And your program will read the entire command line arguments.

But What you are doing (`$ ls -l | ./main.out`) is piping standard output of the command `ls -l` into the standard input of the program `./main.out`.

To read from `stdin`, do
Something like:

```
 std::string value;
 while(std::getline(std::cin, value)){
       std::cout << value << std::endl;
 }
```

See [Reading piped input with C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446161/reading-piped-input-with-c)
 and http://www.site.uottawa.ca/~lucia/courses/2131-05/labs/Lab3/CommandLineArguments.html