# How to get the input and output in c++ using the < and > commands?

Tags: c++

I'm having a problem to find information about what these command does, what do they return and how to get them on my application in c++.
That's an exercise and this is how I need to get the input file I'll be reading from and the output file I'll writing to:

```
myApp < input.txt > output.txt
```

I tried to access it using:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
   cout << argv[1] << endl;
}
```

But I didn't get anything back. I suspect that the argv[1] is an ifstream or something like that. What is it? Or it comes to my main function as a simple string?
Should I receive more parameters on int main to get the "<" and ">" as files?

The answer suggested doesn't solve my problem. I wanted to know how the < and > commands work and the link suggested shows how to use piped cin and cout. Now I know it's a piped cin and cout, but I didn't know how the command line worked and linked to that.

Thank you!

Comment: [ifstream example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream#Example)

Comment: On my application I'm already reading and writing to a file like this. But instead of having like  std::string filename = "Test.b";, when I start the application I need to pass the files as arguments. Like this: myApp < input.txt > output.txt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading piped input with C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446161/reading-piped-input-with-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `myApp < input.txt > output.txt` you redirect `stdin` to be read from `input.txt` and `stdout` to write to `output.txt`. So you handle input and output just like you would if a console was attached to your program.

Comment: Hmmm! So if I do a cout << "test" << endl; it will go to the output.txt file?

Comment: @PalomaSchkrab It should, yes.

Answer (score 3):

`argv` contains [command line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024197/what-does-int-argc-char-argv-mean). `< input.txt` is part of the shell syntax and pipes the contents of the file to standard input instead. If you want to read from that, [you're looking for `cin`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446161/reading-piped-input-with-c).