# Pass each output of a for loop written in shell script to a c++ program with each run of the c++ program

Tags: c++, shell, scripting

I am new to shell script and trying to write a shell script which has various for loops in it. This output is to be fed as input to the c++ program each time I run it. For example say I have a for loop with no.of tasks/no of users etc written in shell script. Now when i run the c++ program i want each value of each for loop like 1,2...6, 1,2,3 (if 6 is the range for max no.of tasks and if 3 is the range for max no.of users) to be fed as input to my c++ program each time i run my cpp program(every time with a new value).

```
//Shell script named script.sh
for NoofTasks in {1..6}; 
do
    echo $NoofTasks
done

for NoofUsers in {1..3}; 
do
    echo $NoofUsers
done`

//actual cpp
int main() {
    cout << "Enter the number of tasks: ";
    cin>>NoOfTasks;
    cout << "Enter the number of servers: ";
    cin>>NoOfUsers; 
    // next calculations depends upon NoOfTasks
    cout << " The list of periodicity values for " << NoOfTasks << " tasks are:" << '\n';
    int periodicity[NoOfTasks];
    for (int i=0; i<NoOfTasks; ++i) {
        periodicity[i] = rand_normal(15,1.6);
        cout << periodicity[i] << '\n';
    }... so on

tried using:-
system("script.sh"); inplace of cout and cin statements but not getting
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess that article explains what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446161/reading-piped-input-with-c.

Comment: sorry, didnt actually help what i am looking for. Any for loop(used in shell script) calling example in a cpp file would have helped.  Still thanks !

Comment: Why do you need to run the script from inside the C++ program? It's much easier to redirect input and output from the shell.

Comment: The link I sent is showing how you 'pipe' the shell information to your c++ program. You can echo the both parameters. However you can have it much more simple when you pass those values simply as arguments .

Comment: A C++ program can receive input from standard input or as parameters that get passed into `main()`. Every C++ textbook will describe and discuss how either approach works, and how to use it. What, specifically, in your textbook's explanation is unclear?

Comment: As you're c++ is expecting two separate inputs, you can't run your program inside of two for loops. I would generate you input pairs into an array, and then loop on the one input array, spliting apart the 2 inputs and passing them in as needed. If you're doing this a proof of concept for something more serious, then look at the `expect` utilities. Good luck.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The thing is I have a c++ program which I do not want to disturb bcz it has lot of necessary things and I do not want to rewrite it. Just that I want to take the user inputs automatically instead of giving it each time from the terminal. Thus I need a script which will do the work of automatic input generation for each variable such that with each run of the cpp program I will get new inputs automatically fed to my program. For this how should I write and associate the script with my cpp file? @Community @shelter@molbdnilo@Sam Varshavchik

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a lot of time, but maybe this will point you in the right direction (after rereading my comment) `NoofUsers=({1..3}) ;
for u in "${NoofUsers[@]}" ; do echo $u ; done ;

indx=0 ;
for NoofTasks in {1..6}; do
  echo ${NoofTasks[@]} ;
  echo ${NoofUsers[$((indx++))]} ;
done` . Note that becuase you have different ranges of numbers in your two variables, you'll need logic inside the loop to decide what to do when `NoofUsers` runs out. `case $NoofUser[$indx] in "" ) indx=0 ;; esac` might be what you want. Good luck.

Comment: The break in the line between `"$` and `{NoofUsers[@]}"` is something to do with this systems comment formatting, it is really all one word. But I really think you should be educating yourself about the `expect` utility. There are plenty Q/A here and it shouldn't be hard to find a decent tutorial. (or look or an O'Reilly book maybe).